# How to keep Visual Studio or Docker from changing the host port numbers?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, visual-studio-2019

I have dockerized my web application and can run it within Visual Studio, however, the host port number it chooses to use is not consistent.

[image]

Where do I configure it to always use the same port numbers?

Comment: it appears the default docker-compose file that VS2019 doesn't explicitally defin the host ports in the config. It exposes port 80 and 443 from the container to the host, but doesn't say what they should map to. should be `80:80` and `443:443` instead of just `80` and `443`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I found I can do this by editing `launchSettings.json` and specifying the values there. This is similar to Arjun's answer, but as far as I can tell there's no UI to add the port numbers like when selecting IIS Express - so you have to edit the file directly.

[image]

**Update:** Actually, in my case, I still had problems getting the port numbers to be consistent after doing this. What worked for me was right-clicking on the project and adding "Container Orchestration Support". Then set the port numbers in the docker-compose project. This helped with overriding environment variables as well.

**Update 2:** For anyone changing the port numbers in `launchSettings.json`, you may also need to delete any existing containers and/or images for the changes to take effect. Cleaning the solution wasn't sufficient for me. I had to delete them from Docker Desktop.

Comment: This should be in the documentation! Had the same issue because my API had a SwaggerUI that required it's port to be fixed because of my Auth-Callback!

Edit: There's actually some docs about it availble on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-launch-settings?view=vs-2019 but they're almost hidden when going thru the quickstart

Comment: `sslPort` is the one that did it for me. The `launchSettings.json` is located under [Project]/Properties for anyone looking.

Comment: The link in the comment above from @AlvesRC is very useful.

Answer (score 12):

I set the port in docker-compose.yml, but it didn't work.
Turns out it was overriden by docker-compose.override.yml.

You can either:

- set the ports inside override (applies always)
- change it in docker-compose.yml and remove it from override (you can then set different ports for different configurations)

[image: docker-compose file structure]

[image: docker-compose port change]

Answer (score 10):

In your projects launchSettings.json add the following items (in yellow):

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There is no UI but you can modify the .csproj project file to add DockerfileRunArguments

```
<PropertyGroup> 
 <DockerLaunchAction>LaunchBrowser</DockerLaunchAction>
 <DockerLaunchUrl>http://{ServiceIPAddress}</DockerLaunchUrl>
 <DockerfileRunArguments>-p 8080:80</DockerfileRunArguments>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Edit:

If you are using NetCore then you can go with the launchSettings.json solution.  For the framework, you can either use "Container Orchestration Support" or this hack.

Comment: `DockerfileRunArguments` seems to be the simplest way to prevent VS2019 from cooking up random port numbers during `docker run`, without the need for an explicit `docker-compose.override`. Note that httpPort and sslPort in launchSettings 'assume' a hard coded container port of 80/443 respectively.

Answer (score 3):

After adding docker-compose orchestration support from within VS2019 I had the same issue. I fixed it by changing

```
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "443"
```

to

```
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
```

According to the [docker-compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports), ports are configured in the following way: -

> Either specify both `ports (HOST:CONTAINER)`, or just the container port (an ephemeral host port is chosen).

So since the host ports aren't defined in the default VS2019 docker-compose file, These are chosen `ephemerally`. I had to look up the definition of this word which appears to be a synonym of transient.

> lasting for a very short time.

Answer (score 3):

I tried setting `"httpPort": 8080` in launchSettings.json, but it didn't work at all, even after removing and recreating the container.

What worked for me was:

Right click project in Visual Studio > `Add` > `Container Orchestration Support` (if you've set this up already, you don't need to do it again)

This sets up a `docker-compose.yml` file, with a `Dockerfile` for the app. There's also a `docker-compose.override.yml` file that's used for overriding the `docker-compose.yml` with environment-specific settings (e.g. for dev, or prod). By default, this exposes the container port as port `80`, but doesn't expose a fixed host port to map the container port ot. To change it (e.g. to map a fixed host port of `8080`):

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  coreapp:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

**Note the use of double quotes** i.e. `"8080:80"`

Comment: That is the correct answer. With Docker, the port binding can only be set on the command line when you run the container. The way you can define run parameters from a config file is to use a docker-compose file. 
Setting the port in the projet launchSettings or in the docker-compose launchSettings have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and had to modify docker-compose.override.yml in the docker-compose project.

Originally, the ports section looked like that (which was causing automatic port assignments):

```
ports:
  - "80"
  - "443"
```

I changed it to

```
ports:
  - "8080:80"
  - "56850:443"
```

And that forced the Debug to use the ports specified.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was able to find it with the following steps in Visual Studio 2017:

1. Right click on the web project, then click Properties.
2. Click on the Debug tab.
3. Under the Profile IIS Express, you will find the port at the App URL box.

For more, visit: [Docker Port Managing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/docker/docker_managing_ports.htm)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not launching IIS Express. When I added docker support, a profile named "Docker" was added on the Debug tab and under the "Launch" dropdown appears a "Docker" option. There is no place to specify a port number like on the IIS Express option - unless maybe you specify it in the "Application arguments" or "Enviroment variables"?

Comment: I figured out how to do it despite not having a UI in Visual Studio for Docker (see the answer I posted). Still, I'll award you the answer since you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Marking the wrong answer to be nice is nice and all, but it's very confusing for readers looking for the real answer. Please mark your own answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: @mikesigs, I've done that in the past and then got called out for NOT marking the answer that helped me find the real answer. I guess you can't make everyone happy, but you're right. I've changed the accepted answer. Still, people should not be downvoting this answer. It's still a valid answer that can help some.

Comment: @Stefan, see comment above

Comment: @adam0101: thank you for taking the time to update :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've found this question when I searched for decision - in my container there asn't port redirect, because my csproj has

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">
```

instead of

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

So change Worker -> Web makes VS2022 to generate valid dotnet build / run commands